# Russian dolls - Find the minimum dolls left

Tags: java, list, algorithm

I have N [dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) of various sizes.

I can put the smaller dolls inside the larger ones, but dolls of the exact same size cannot be placed inside each other.

I have to find the minimum number of dolls that remain when the maximum number of dolls have been packed.

> **Constraints**
> 1≤N≤ 10<sup>5</sup>
> 1 ≤ size of doll ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>
>
> **Output** Print the minimum number of dolls after placing all smaller dolls inside the larger dolls.
>
> **Example #1**
>
> Input 2, 2, 3, 3
> Output 2
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> - Put the doll at index `1` inside the doll at index `3` i.e. the doll of size two into the doll size three.
> - Put a doll at index `2` inside the doll at index `4` i.e. doll of size two in size three
>
> We are left with two dolls of size three, which cannot be further placed inside each other. So, the output is `2`.
>
> **Example #2**
>
> Input 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5
> Output 2
>
> **Explanation:** We can place dolls at index (1, 2, 4, 5) in the doll at index 6.
> So, we will remain with two dolls of sizes two and five.

This is my code:

```
public int process(List<Integer> doll) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for(int key : doll) map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key,0)+1);
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    int maxKey = list.get(list.size()-1);
    int m = map.get(maxKey);
    int result = 0;
    for(int k : map.keySet()) {
        if(k != maxKey) {
            int p = map.get(k);
            if(p > m){
                result += p - m;
            }
        }
    }
    result += m;
    return result;
}
```

Out of 7 test cases, 3 were failing, and they are HIDDEN test cases so I am not able to see those cases.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `v`? It's not being used anywhere. Edit: This doesn't compile, we can't help you if you don't post all your code.

Comment: Why compare every doll size to the `maxKey`?

Comment: Explain your algorithm in English. But also create some of your own test data and try to find cases which fail.

Comment: @Water, it was a typo error, I have fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand example 2. Shouldn't the output be 1 because you can fit 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 inside of each other, leaving only the 2?

Comment: @Water, Input is 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 . I have two 2's, I can only place a single 2 inside 5. So in the 5 we can place 1,2,3,4. So in the end we have 5 and 2 remaining numbers

Comment: It doesn't say in the problem statement that the dolls are guaranteed to be sorted by size, and your algorithm probably doesn't work if they're not.

Comment: @learner _"I can only place a single 2 inside 5"_. Where is this specified in the question?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Placing more than one doll of the same size into a larger doll might be physically impossible ([this doll](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Matthew-Frank-5/publication/265969561/figure/fig5/AS:668769798078474@1536458553275/Matryoshka-shell-model-a-Set-of-Matryoshka-dolls-in-order-of-size-35-and-b.ppm) is a kind of nested, wooden toy). And it can be observed from the example.

Comment: Try 1, 1, 2, 2, 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can put the smaller dolls inside the larger ones, but dolls of the exact same size cannot be placed inside each other.

Basically you need to find the most frequent size of the dolls, it would be equal to the number of remaining dolls.

Because only duplicated sizes impose limitation on how many dolls would leave after placing dolls of smaller sizes into larger dolls.

Let's consider the following example with `16` dolls of sizes from `1` to `5`:

```
   ---   SIZES   --- 
+----------------------+
|  1   2   3   4   5   | -> doll of size 5 containing [4, 3, 2, 1]
|      2   3   4   5   | -> doll of size 5 containing [4, 3, 2]
|      2   3   4   5   | -> doll of size 5 containing [4, 3, 2]
|          3   4       | -> doll of size 4 containing [3]
|          3           | -> empty doll of size 3
+----------------------+
```

After folding the data by placing all smaller dolls into large dolls, we would have `5` dolls:

- `3` dolls of size `5`;
- `1` doll of size `4`;
- `1` doll of size `3`;

The total number of dolls is bounded by the most frequent size.

```
public static int process(List<Integer> doll) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> sizeByCount = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int size : doll) {
        sizeByCount.merge(size, 1, Integer::sum); // or sizeByCount.put(size, sizeByCount.getOrDefault(size, 0) + 1);
    }
    
    int max = 0;
    
    for (int count : sizeByCount.values()) {
        max = Math.max(count, max);
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

In case if you're comfortable with Streams API, this code can be replaced with a single statement:

```
return doll.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> 1, Integer::sum))
    .values().stream()
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
    .orElse(0);
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(process(List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
    System.out.println(process(List.of(2, 2, 3, 3)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
2
2
```

Comment: (sorry for changing the constraints from 105 to 10<sup>5</sup>)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks, fifth power of ten - that makes sense. Boundary `105` was fishy)